# translating linux df command output

Tags: linux

I got email from my network administrator that server space is fulled and that is why its having issue. I got this in his email. Can anyone please tell what does 64Z means here ?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       64Z   64Z     0 100% /
```

Comment: Use `man` or `info` to get that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's info from `man df`

```
SIZE may be (or may be an integer optionally followed by) one  of  fol‐
   lowing: KB 1000, K 1024, MB 1000*1000, M 1024*1024, and so on for G, T,
   P, E, Z, Y.
```

Z means:

```
ZettaByte = 1,180,591,620,717,411,303,424 Bytes
```

You have a big disk :)

Comment: You should probably mention that Z is Zetabytes, as that is not explicit in the man page. And yes - that is one whopping big disk! I wonder if he works for CERN?!

Comment: I am not so sure that my large amazon instance has that much big disk :).

Answer (score 1):

That is a zettabyte which is big, really big.

ZettaByte (ZB) 1,180,591,620,717,411,303,424 bytes or 1,024 EB

[Wikipedia - File Size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_size)